# CF9 EntityDelete: How to delete entities

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

If I have an array of entities, whats the easiest way of deleting the entire array of entities (or to put it this way, the entire ORM table)? I have:

```
<cfset allUsers = EntityLoad("User", {}, false)/>
```

Now to delete all the entities, would I use some sort of a loop? If so, how do I access individual entity primary keys within? I tried:

```
<cfset userTemp = EntityLoad("User", allUsers[i].User.userID, true) />
```

but that didn't work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EntityLoad will return an array of the entity objects so we can loop over that and use entityDelete:

```
<cfloop array="#allUsers#" index="User">
   <cfset entityDelete( User )>
</cfloop>
```

As ever when deleting data be careful!  I generally prefer a soft delete.

Comment: I presume this should end with a cfloop tag, not a cfif

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to use array notation, you do it like this.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(allUsers)#" index="i">
    <cfset entityDelete( allUsers[i] )>
</cfloop>
```

Another way to do this without making ColdFusion do all the work is to execute a query.

```
<cfset ormexecutequery("DELETE FROM User",true)>
```

Answer (score 0):

If deleting the array (in terms of freeing memory) is what you want to do, the following should work:

```
<cfset allUsers = "">
<!--- or --->
<cfset StructDelete(variables, "allUsers")>
```

Of course this would only remove one reference. If the objects (allUsers or the individual array members) are referenced someplace else, these references would continue to work.